# Catch only some runtime errors in Python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, runtime-error

I'm importing a module which raises the following error in some conditions:
    RuntimeError: pyparted requires root access

I know that I can just check for root access before the import, but I'd like to know how to catch this spesific kind of error via a try/except statement for future reference. Is there any way to differentiate between this RuntimeError and others that might be raised?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know that I can just check for root access before the import, but I'd like to know how to catch this spesific kind of error via a try/except statement for future reference. Is there any way to differentiate between this RuntimeError and others that might be raised?

If the error is caused by a specific condition, then I think the easiest way to catch the error is to test for the condition, and you can raise a more specific error yourself. After all the 'error' exists before the error is thrown, since in this case its a problem with the environment.

I agree with those above - text matching on an error is kind of a terrifying prospect.

Answer (score 15):

You can check attributes of the exception to differentiate from other possible `RuntimeError` exceptions. For example, re-raise the error if it does not match a predefined message text.

```
    try:
        import pypatred
    except RuntimeError,e:
        if e.message == 'RuntimeError: pyparted requires root access':
            return 'pyparted - no root access'
        raise
```

Of course, direct text comparison is just an example, you could search for included substrings or regular expressions.

It is worth noting that the `.message` attribute of exceptions is [deprecated starting with Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes). You can find the text in `.args`, usually `args[0]`.

> ... For 2.6, the `message` attribute is being deprecated in favor of the `args` attribute.

Comment: and you'll need to change this every time developers change a letter in the error message.

Comment: This is bad! you should not compare error message like that unless it is absolutely unavoidable.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like in this case comparing the error message *is* unavoidable — pyparted doesn't appear to raise a more specific error.

Answer (score 5):

```
try:
    import pyparted
except RuntimeError:
    print('RuntimeError is raised')
    raise
```

more on [exception handling in tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

This situation should produce [`ImportError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html?highlight=exception#exceptions.ImportError) in my opinion. And you can do it yourself:

```
try:
    import pyparted
except RuntimeError as e:
    raise ImportError(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

[RuntimeError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError) Raised when an error is detected that doesn’t fall in any of the other categories

```
def foo():
   try:
      foo()
   except RuntimeError, e:
      print e
      print " Runtime Error occurred due to exceeded maximum recursion depth "
```

That is how we will catch the RuntimeError caused by the exceeded recursion limit in python

And if you want to call your function over the recursion limit you can do the following

```
import sys
def foo():
     try:
        foo()
     except RuntimeError, e:
        sys.setrecursionlimit(1200)
        foo()
```

But always it is highly not recommended to change the recursion limit, 
but very small changes in  the recursion limit are allowed

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
   try:
        import module
   except RuntimeError:
         pass
```

imports are interpreted as any other statement, they are not special. You could do an

```
if condition:
     import module
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
   import ...
except RuntimeError:
   # Do something
```